# Adding a local variable into a trigger gives error

Tags: apex, after-trigger

I'm working on creating a trigger that uses one of the methods from the URL class and has a local variable. When I don't use a local variable it works but when I try to introduce a string it give me an error.

This works:

```
trigger composite_graph on Opportunity (after update) {
    System.debug(URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm());
}
```

However, I want to use the value of the URL in some other places in my trigger logic so I try to assign the value to a string variable like this.

```
trigger composite_graph on Opportunity (after update) {
    String url = URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();
    System.debug(url);
}
```

For some reason the second sample that stores the result of `URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm()` in the variable `url` gives me the error `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getCurrentRequestUrl() from the type String`

The method `toExternalForm()` does return a string so I should be able to store that in the string variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `String url = System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();`

The reason being, you're creating a string call 'url', and you're trying to reference something called 'URL'.

With the System namespace, the namespace is implicit so you don't usually need to use the System prefix, but because you've named a variable with the same name as one of the System classes, you need to explicitly use the System namespace.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to an effect called [Name Shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm). Basically, when you create a class or variable that conflicts with a system class, your local copy takes predence. In addition, Apex is case-insensitive, such that URL, uRl, url, etc, all refer to the same name in code.

It's for this reason that more seasoned developers will warn you against using class and variable names like `Schema`, `Test`, `sObjectType`, and so on. Doing this tends to cause unintended problem. As an example, consider:

```
Integer a = 5, b = 10;
String math = 'Hello';
Integer largerNumber = Math.max(a, b);
```

Will fail to compile.

Also, at least some developers, including me, will advise that some sort of descriptive name should be used for variables. `url` is generic, but `currentUrl` is descriptive; as your code grows, it won't be as obvious what a `url` is, but `currentUrl` should be a sufficient reminder of what the contents are.

Comment: thanks, that interesting. I didn't realize Apex worked that way. Your above code would work in many other languages. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @James Yeah, Apex's design choices are interesting, to say the least. Few languages are case-insensitive *and* have name shadowing. I won't say unique, because I'm probably wrong, but it's rare enough in my travels that it stands out as a unique combination of subtle traps in Apex.